# Infinite loop while creating new gpg key

Tags: gnupg

I am trying to create new GPG key. I am stuck at creating passphrase. I putting my 50+ symbols length phrase into input from clipboard, and then it answers me again. And there is no end of it. How can I create gpg key?

GPG version: 2.3.6 (by Brew)

Comment: This sounds like typical behaviour when you're inputting an invalid passphrase.

Comment: @Maritim what is the valid passphrase? It shouldn't include whitespaces? Or something else?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solve this including digits in the passphrase.